# Azure ACR: why can i push to ACR having ONLY AcrPull role?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks, docker-registry, acr

I created a private registry having only `AcrPull` role, as showing below :

[image]

But when i build my own image and **PUSH**, it works fine! (instead of deny me )

I would like to know why ? (since it has only `AcrPull` and NOT `AcrPush` )

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that you have other roles as well? 
E.g. Contributor or Owner? RBAC Roles cannot deny an action.

Comment: Check your permissions.. For troubleshooting you may ask your colleague or use different ID to test it with least privilege's.

Comment: @JulianHüppauff i confirm, i have one and only one role which is AcrPull. you can even try it, and keep me informed

Comment: @DillyB i am pushing from my local machine and it works with AcrPull

Comment: @Mohamed - there are 12  items on your role assignments page, you are showing us only 1. Secondly, how did you authenticate with Acr from your local machine?

Comment: Can use the "Check Access" Tab to check your user? Can you post a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have created the ACR yourself (that's what I understand from your post), you have also the `Owner` role. That enables push as well (as does `Contributor` role).

As suggested in the comments, when you try with a different user account that has no such permissions, push will not work.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles?tabs=azure-cli